# how to see full code in storybook by using Storybook Storysource Addon

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon

I use next Js and typescript in this project.

I want to see all the code in the component(checkboxSquare.tsx) but only i can see **(args) => <CheckboxSquare {...args} />** .

This is **CheckboxSquare.stories.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

import { Meta, Story } from "@storybook/react";
import CheckboxSquare, { CheckboxT } from "./CheckboxSquare";

export default {
  title: "Components/CheckBoxSquare",
  component: CheckboxSquare,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<CheckboxT> = (args) => <CheckboxSquare {...args} />;

export const Basic = Template.bind({});
Basic.args = {
  checked: true,
  disabled: false,
};
```

And this is **CheckboxSquare.tsx**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useState } from "react";

const CheckboxLayout = styled("input")<CheckboxT>`
  ... skip
`;

export interface CheckboxT extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  checked?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

const Checkbox = ({ checked, disabled }: CheckboxT) => {
  return (
    <CheckboxLayout
      type={"checkbox"}
      disabled={disabled}
      checked={onClick ? checked : checkedState}
      readOnly
    />
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

And I install **npm install @storybook/addon-storysource --dev** so in **story tab**
I only see this code **(args) => <CheckboxSquare {...args} />**
and this is my .stroybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-storysource",
      options: {
        loaderOptions: {
          injectStoryParameters: false,
          prettierConfig: { printWidth: 80, singleQuote: false },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
};
```

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/storysource in this link
example show all code in tsx file. how to like this??

Answer (score 0):

From their readme: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/storysource

> Storybook 6.0 introduced an unintentional change to source-loader, in
> which only the source of the selected story is shown in the addon. To
> restore the old behavior, pass theinjectStoryParameters: false option.
>
> If you're using addon-docs:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   addons: [
>     {
>       name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
>       options: {
>         sourceLoaderOptions: {
>           injectStoryParameters: false,
>         },
>       },
>     },
>   ],
> };
> ```
>
> If not:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   addons: [
>     {
>       name: '@storybook/addon-storysource',
>       options: {
>         loaderOptions: {
>           injectStoryParameters: false,
>         },
>       },
>     },
>   ],
> };
> ```
>
> This bug will be resolved in a future version of the addon.

I see you are using the essentials addon, which I believe includes the `addon-docs` addon, so you might want to try adding the following to your addons:

```
{
  name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
  options: {
    sourceLoaderOptions: {
      injectStoryParameters: false,
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: **Storybook v7** - *Error: Addon-docs no longer uses source-loader in 7.0*